# Erlang distribution and Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems, central-limit-theorem

Let $X\sim\textrm{Erlang}(k,\lambda)$. Use the Central Limit Theorem to evaluate

$\underset{k\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\mathbb{P}\left(\left|X-\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]\right|>\epsilon \cdot \mathbb{E}\left[X\right]\right)$

where $\epsilon>0$ but small.

Comment: HINT: A property of the Erlang distribution is that it is the sum of $k$ i.i.d. random variables $Y_i$ which are exponentially distributed with rate $\lambda$. Do you see now how to use the central limit theorem?

Comment: No, I don't see it. If $Y_i\sim\textrm{Exp}(\lambda)$, then  $\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i\sim\textrm{Erlang}(k,\lambda)$. Ok. But how I do use the central limit theorem?

Comment: Further on @AlexR.'s hint: CLT gives $(X-kE(Y_i))/\sqrt{k\cdot Var(Y_i)}$ as $k\to\infty$. So, find $E(Y_1)$ and $Var(Y_i)$, then put $P(|X-E(X)|\gt\epsilon\cdot E(X))$ into form $P(|(X-kE(Y_i))/\sqrt{k\cdot Var(Y_i)}| \gt ?)$.

Comment: Ok. $\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\dfrac{X-\dfrac{1}{\lambda}}{\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{\lambda^{2}}}}\right|>?\right)$. And now? I don't see it.

Comment: I think it should be $P\left(\left|\dfrac{X-k/\lambda}{\sqrt{k/\lambda^2}}\right| \gt ?\right)$. (You missed a $k$.) Now, CLT has $\dfrac{X-k/\lambda}{\sqrt{k/\lambda^2}} \sim N(0,1)$ as $k\to\infty$. You also know $E(X)=k/\lambda$. You seek $P\left(\left|X-k/\lambda\right| \gt \epsilon k/\lambda\right)$. Divide both sides by $\sqrt{k/\lambda^2}$ so the probability involves an expression that has $N(0,1)$ distribution. Then you can write this probability in terms of $\Phi$ (standard normal cdf) and then deduce the limit.

Comment: $Z \sim N(0,1)$. We have $\mathbb{P}\left(\left|X-\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]\right|>\epsilon\cdot\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\left|X-\dfrac{k}{\lambda}\right|>\epsilon \dfrac{k}{\lambda}\right)=$

Comment: $=\mathbb{P}\left(\dfrac{\left|X-k/\lambda\right|}{\sqrt{k/\lambda^{2}}}>\dfrac{\epsilon\cdot k/\lambda}{\sqrt{k/\lambda^{2}}}\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(Z>\dfrac{\epsilon\cdot k/\lambda}{\sqrt{k/\lambda^{2}}}\right)=$

Comment: $=\mathbb{P}\left(Z>\epsilon\sqrt{k}\right)$ when $k\to\infty$ then $\mathbb{P}\left(Z>\infty\right)=0$ k It's ok?

Comment: TripleX, does the value of $\epsilon$ matter? See my answer

Comment: No one cannot use the CLT with moving bounds as you suggest in the comments, one needs either to use the proper theorem (namely, the LLN), or, if one insists, to be *much more precise* in the application of the CLT.

Comment: @Did What if we say: Choose $\delta\gt 0$. Let $M\gt0$ be such that $\Phi(-M)=\delta/4$. Then by CLT, $P\left(\left|\dfrac{X-k/\lambda}{\sqrt{k/\lambda^2}}\right|\gt M\right)=1-P\left(\left|\dfrac{X-k/\lambda}{\sqrt{k/\lambda^2}}\right|\leq M\right)\to1-\int_{-M}^M\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-x^2/2)\;dx=\delta/2$ as $k\to\infty$. So there exists $K$ s.t. $\epsilon\sqrt{K}\geq M$ and $P\left(\left|\dfrac{X-k/\lambda}{\sqrt{k/\lambda^2}}\right|\gt \epsilon\sqrt{k}\right)\lt \delta\quad\forall\; k\gt K$. ...

Comment: @Did ... We may choose $\delta$ arbitrarily small, so $\lim_{k\to\infty}P\left(\left|\dfrac{X-k/\lambda}{\sqrt{k/\lambda^2}}\right|\gt \epsilon\sqrt{k}\right)=0$.

Comment: @MickA Yep, *that* works.

Comment: @TripleX Careful. Z depends on k.

Answer (score -1):

According to Larsen and Marx, the central limit theorem states that:

---

[image]

---

$$\underset{k\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\mathbb{P}\left(\left|X-\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]\right|>\epsilon \cdot \mathbb{E}\left[X\right]\right)$$

$$= 1 - \underset{k\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\mathbb{P}\left(\left|X-\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]\right|\le\epsilon \cdot \mathbb{E}\left[X\right]\right)$$

Let us try to use the central limit theorem on

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\left|X-\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]\right|\le\epsilon \cdot \mathbb{E}\left[X\right]\right)$$

$$= \mathbb{P}\left( -\epsilon \cdot \mathbb{E}\left[X\right] \le X-\mathbb{E}\left[X\right] \le \epsilon \cdot \mathbb{E}\left[X\right]\right)$$

$$= \mathbb{P}\left( -\epsilon \cdot \frac{k}{\lambda} \le (W_1 + ... + W_k)-\frac{k}{\lambda} \le \epsilon \cdot \frac{k}{\lambda} \right)$$

$$= \mathbb{P}\left( \frac{-\epsilon \cdot \frac{k}{\lambda}}{\frac{\sqrt{k}}{\lambda}} \le \frac{(W_1 + ... + W_k)-\frac{k}{\lambda}}{\frac{\sqrt{k}}{\lambda}} \le \frac{\epsilon \cdot \frac{k}{\lambda}}{\frac{\sqrt{k}}{\lambda}} \right)$$

$$= \mathbb{P}\left( -\epsilon \sqrt{k} \le \frac{(W_1 + ... + W_k)-\frac{k}{\lambda}}{\frac{\sqrt{k}}{\lambda}} \le \epsilon \sqrt{k} \right)$$

Unfortunately, our 'a' and 'b' here depend on k. Nevertheless, assuming I am interpreting my stochastic calculus class notes correctly, CLT is still applicable (if the random variable didn't depend on k, I think we could've used continuity of probability):

$$= \lim_{k \to \infty} \mathbb{P}\left( -\epsilon \sqrt{k} \le \frac{(W_1 + ... + W_k)-\frac{k}{\lambda}}{\frac{\sqrt{k}}{\lambda}} \le \epsilon \sqrt{k} \right)$$

$$= \mathbb{P}\left( \lim_{k \to \infty} -\epsilon \sqrt{k} \le \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{(W_1 + ... + W_k)-\frac{k}{\lambda}}{\frac{\sqrt{k}}{\lambda}} \le \lim_{k \to \infty} \epsilon \sqrt{k} \right)$$

$$= \mathbb{P}\left( -\infty < Z < \infty \right) = 1$$

Hence

$$\underset{k\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\mathbb{P}\left(\left|X-\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]\right|>\epsilon \cdot \mathbb{E}\left[X\right]\right)$$

$$= 1 - \underset{k\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\mathbb{P}\left(\left|X-\mathbb{E}\left[X\right]\right|\le\epsilon \cdot \mathbb{E}\left[X\right]\right)$$

$$= 1 - 1 = 0$$